# Method does not exist when moving Symfony 2 project to production

Tags: symfony, centos

I'm trying to move a Symfony 2 based project to production mode on my rented CentOS VPS, however I seem to encounter an issue when visiting a certain route address which shows the following error every time.

`Method "MyNamespace\MyProjectBundle\Controller\MyController::indexAction" does not exist.
500 Internal Server Error - InvalidArgumentException`

If I run `rm -rf app/cache/*` it will load fine, then show the same error when I refresh again. It appears to work fine in development mode. From what I can see all of the permissions are fine and have verified all of the routes are working using `php app/console router:debug`.

Can anyone else suggest what could be causing this issue?

Comment: can you please provide the parts of your app/logs/prod.log where the error is logged ?

Answer (score 0):

Check your /app/AppKernel.php

```
if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
            $bundles[] = new Acme\ProjectBundle\ProjectDemoBundle();
```

Comment: Sorry, the method which cannot be found is within a bundle I created, rather than a demo one. I've updated my question to clarify this.